# Create a form with phpMyAdmin on backbone

Tags: javascript, database, backbone.js

I would like to know if it's possible to connecting a form to database (phpmyadmin) with Backbone ?

It's just to add emails newsletters.

Tks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin is not a database. It is an application used to access MySQL databases via a browser-based UI.

There are MySQL libraries for javascript being run from a server (like in node.js), but you do not want to be connecting to a database from your client.  You would need an intermediary web service.

Running from a client would be extremely foolish in that you would a) have to open up database access from potentially any remote host in the world and b) you would have your database login credentials exposed to your clients.

Comment: Client side. I just want to store the emails in a file eg

Comment: @Dossp You need to use a server-side script to store this data into a database.

Comment: Ok tks ! i understand better now